# Freeze/Hide Question/Answer or show as "Preview"

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, edits, time

**My suggestion is whether a Freeze/Hide functionality would be useful within the 1-5 minutes of a new Question/Answer?**

What about a "preview" grace period where people can vote on something, but it doesn't show until the author has expended his/her "edit time"?

To Elaborate:

I answered a question with some code, knowing it would work. However, I noticed a bug and so needed to compile the code and double-check it. Not wanting to be down-voted, I actually deleted my answer so no one would be able to see it. Then, I did my double checking and 5 minutes later I undeleted my post and edited it with some run-time checks/exception handling. This seems like overkill when all I wanted was to "hide" my answer for a little while.

Answer (score 6):

How about you double check your answers before you post them? And only post them when you feel absolutely confident that they won't get downvoted?

[Fastest Gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) has been a problem since the very early days of Stack Overflow, one of the more persistent problems we ever had. I'm afraid your feature would only serve to encourage people posting quick and dirty answers, instead of taking the time to elaborate a bit and actually explain stuff. Nothing inherently wrong with quick and dirty answers, they can be useful, but there's no point in further encouraging them.

Answer (score 4):

*Click delete* -> hidden

*Click undelete* -> shows again

Where is the overkill in that? How would a show/hide button be better?